# Variable of type 'class' in Typescript

Tags: class, dynamic, typescript

I'd like to do this:

```
createClass(c:class):SomeInstance {
   return new class() as SomeInstance;
}
```

However, it says 'type expected' where I specify the :class part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed :

```
function createClass<SomeInstance>(c:{new():SomeInstance}):SomeInstance {
   return new c();
}
```

## More

You are basically saying that `createClass` takes a constructor (something that when called with new gives an instance) hence `c:{new():SomeInstance}`. And then the return type of `createClass` is that `SomeInstance`

> PS: probably call it `createInstance`

Comment: What does the <SomeInstance> part do? Is this a generic thing?

Comment: @nizzle its called a `generic` type argument. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html